# 2 PHP switchs at the same time

Tags: php, switch-statement, case

I have a little problem, I hope you guys can help me out with this!

So I added a PHP switch for loading pages and a login system with switch for actions, but when I register I get redirected to index.

I will show my code:

Register.php:

```
//if logged in redirect to members page
if( $user->is_logged_in() ){ header('Location: index.php?page=profile'); }

//if form has been submitted process it
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){


//very basic validation
if(strlen($_POST['username']) < 3){
    $error[] = 'Username is too short.';
} else {
    $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT username FROM members WHERE username = :username');
    $stmt->execute(array(':username' => $_POST['username']));
    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if(!empty($row['username'])){
        $error[] = 'Username provided is already in use.';
    }

}

if(strlen($_POST['password']) < 3){
    $error[] = 'Password is too short.';
}

if(strlen($_POST['passwordConfirm']) < 3){
    $error[] = 'Confirm password is too short.';
}

if($_POST['password'] != $_POST['passwordConfirm']){
    $error[] = 'Passwords do not match.';
}

//email validation
if(!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
    $error[] = 'Please enter a valid email address';
} else {
    $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT email FROM members WHERE email = :email');
    $stmt->execute(array(':email' => $_POST['email']));
    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if(!empty($row['email'])){
        $error[] = 'Email provided is already in use.';
    }

}


//if no errors have been created carry on
if(!isset($error)){

    //hash the password
    $hashedpassword = $user->password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

    //create the activasion code
    $activasion = md5(uniqid(rand(),true));

    try {

        //insert into database with a prepared statement
        $stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO members (username,password,email,active) VALUES (:username, :password, :email, :active)');
        $stmt->execute(array(
            ':username' => $_POST['username'],
            ':password' => $hashedpassword,
            ':email' => $_POST['email'],
            ':active' => $activasion
        ));
        $id = $db->lastInsertId('memberID');

        //send email
        $to = $_POST['email'];
        $subject = "Registration Confirmation";
        $body = "<p>Thank you for registering at demo site.</p>
        <p>To activate your account, please click on this link: <a href='".DIR."activate.php?x=$id&y=$activasion'>".DIR."activate.php?x=$id&y=$activasion</a></p>
        <p>Regards Site Admin</p>";

        $mail = new Mail();
        $mail->setFrom(SITEEMAIL);
        $mail->addAddress($to);
        $mail->subject($subject);
        $mail->body($body);
        $mail->send();

        //redirect to index page
        header('Location: index.php?page=register?action=joined');
        exit;

    //else catch the exception and show the error.
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        $error[] = $e->getMessage();
    }

}

}
?>
    <form id='register' action='' method='post'
        accept-charset='UTF-8'>
<h3 style="width: 587px;">Register</h3>
                <?php
            //check for any errors
            if(isset($error)){
                foreach($error as $error){
                    echo '<h5 style="background-color: #FF4E4E; border-radius: 5px; border: solid #D30000; 2px ">'.$error.'</h5>';
                }
            }

            //if action is joined show sucess
            if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == 'joined'){
                echo "<h2 class='bg-success'>Registration successful, please check your email to activate your account.</h2>";
            }
            ?>
<br />
<table>
<tr>
<td class="left"><label for='username' >Username*:</label></td>
<td class="mid"><input type='register' name='username' id='username' placeholder="Choose a username" value="<?php if(isset($error)){ echo $_POST['username']; } ?>" maxlength="50" /></td>
<td class="right">TEXT</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label for='email' >Your E-mail*:</label></td>
<td><input type='register' name='email' id='email' placeholder="Enter your E-mail addres" maxlength="50" value="<?php if(isset($error)){ echo $_POST['email']; } ?>" /><td>
<td class="right">TEXT</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label for='password' >Password*:</label></td>
<td><input type='register' name="password" id='password' placeholder="Choose a password" maxlength="50" /></td>
<td class="right">TEXT</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label for='password' >Confirm Password*:</label></td>
<td><input type='register' name="passwordConfirm" id='password' placeholder="Choose a password" maxlength="50" /></td>
<td class="right">TEXT</td>
</tr>
</table>
<center>
<input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Register' />
</center>
</form>
```

Load.php (PHP page switch)

```
error_reporting(0);
switch($_GET['page'])
{
case 'home':
case 'register':
case 'login':
case 'profile':
case 'logout':
    include("pages/$_GET[page].php");
    break;
default:
    include('pages/home.php');
}
```

index.php

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="rightcontent">
        <?php include "main/right-sidebar.php" ?>
    </div>
    <div class="leftcontent">
        <?php include "main/left-sidebar.php" ?>
    </div>
    <div class="midcontent">
        <?php   include "main/load.php"; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you need more information just ask.
I hope you guys got a solution for this, like another way to approach this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is best to post your code in your question, and not in a link, so that if the links die, the question will still be useful to others.

Comment: Use pastebin for chat, not questions

Comment: Sorry guys i am new here on stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

There where you set the header location to `index.php?page=register`, shouldnt you go to `load.php?page=register`
?
Or am I missing something?

Comment: Added the index.php maybe you understand now how the website works.

Comment: That indeed changes things. So you redirect to index and that should redirect to register? Why cant you just redirect to register, why the switch? By doing the double redirect you lose your $_POST variable `action=joined`

Comment: How can i fix this? is there a better way to load pages then?

Comment: Like I mentioned, dont go through index or dont use header location, but usingsomething like historypush is NOT the right way to do it (even though it would work)